# python scraping by getting urls dynamic way

Tags: python, web-crawler, web-scraping

I am new to the world of data scraping,previously used python for web and desktop app development.
I am just wondering,if there is any way to get the urls from a page then look into it for specific information like,phone no,address etc.

Currently I am using BeautifulSoup and built method where I am telling the urls as a parameter of the methods.

The site I am scraping large and its really tough to pass the specific url for each page.

Any suggestion to make it faster and self driven?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/). It simplifies both crawling and parsing (it uses `libxml2` for parsing by default).

Answer (score 0):

Use a more efficient HTML parser, like [lxml](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html). [See here](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/03/30/python-html-parser-performance/) for performance comparisons of various Python parsers.